# How to modify a vector dynamically while iterating over it in R

Tags: python, r, loops, dynamic, iteration

In multiple programming languages, such as python, it is possible to modify dynamically a list while iterating through, i.e. removing the last element

```
    list = [1,2,3,4]
    for i in a:
        a.pop()
```

In this case, if we print i and a on each iteration we will get 2 iterations,

```
    i=1; a=[1,2,3]
    i=2; a=[1,2]
```

However, if we use

```
    a = a[:-1]
```

instead of

```
   a.pop()
```

what we get is four iterations. i = 1:4 and the list each time with one element less.

I am working in R, and want to achieve the first, being able to modify the vector over which i am iterating at the same time i iterate.

Is it possible? How to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you would filter a sequence and create a new one, for example using a list comprehension.

Comment: Do you want  `a[ -length(a)]` ?  If you call that iteratively it'll remove the last element of `a` each time.

Answer (score 1):

R uses "copy on modify", which effectively means in this case that it will be acting like slicing (à la `a = a[:-1]`) rather than modification in place (à la `a.pop()`).   `head(L,-1)` or `L[-length(L)]` or `L[1:(length(L)-1)]` are all equivalent R idioms for Python's `a[:-1]`.

```
L <- as.list(1:4)
for (i in L) { print(length(L)); L=head(L,-1) }
## [1] 4
## [1] 3
## [1] 2
## [1] 1
```

It's rather challenging to get the call-by-reference behaviour in R; I think it's not possible. From `?for`:

> The ‘seq’ in a ‘for’ loop is evaluated at the start of the loop; changing it subsequently does not affect the loop.